# Replacing field names in XML using conditions based on data contained within - during the parsing phase

Tags: splunk

I've had no luck on Splunk Answers so I'm posting here.

Can't figure this one out, any help appreciated. Data is sensitive but I'll try and be as clear as possible.

I have data in a XML files that looks like this:

```
 &lt;ROW&gt;
  &lt;FIELD1&gt;A&lt;/FIELD1&gt;
  &lt;FIELD2&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD2&gt;
  &lt;FIELD3&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD3&gt;
  &lt;FIELD4&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD4&gt;
 &lt;/ROW&gt;
 &lt;ROW&gt;
  &lt;FIELD1&gt;B&lt;/FIELD1&gt;
  &lt;FIELD2&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD2&gt;
  &lt;FIELD3&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD3&gt;
  &lt;FIELD4&gt;randomdata&lt;/FIELD4&gt;
 &lt;/ROW&gt;
```

Now, some of you might recognise this as XML with encoding gone wrong.

I have indexed this data happily using the `SEDCMD` command and replaced the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>` to make it readable XML. Each `ROW` is a new event but multiple are contained in the same XML file.

The difficult question is... I want to change `FIELDS2,3,4` names based on the VALUE of `FIELD1`

So,

If `FIELD1 = A` Replace `FIELD3` with `FIELD99`

IF `FIELD1 = B` Replace `FIELD4` with `FIELD37`

etc...

I have tried using the `[rule::blabla]` stanza in props.conf to assign different sourcetypes. But both `A` and `B` exist in the raw data.

Here's my props.conf

```
[st]
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=true
BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE=&lt;ROW&gt;
NO_BINARY_CHECK=true
disabled=false
DATETIME_CONFIG=NONE
SEDCMD-1=s/&gt;/>/g
SEDCMD-2=s/&lt;/</g
MAX_EVENTS=1000
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in props.conf as follows:

```
EVAL-FIELD3 = if(FIELD1==A,FIELD99,FIELD3)
EVAL-FIELD4 = if(FIELD1==B,FIELD37,FIELD4)
```

If this is a little more complex than you describe, you may need to use a CASE statement.  You can just use eval on the search bar to test your results prior to integrating it into props.conf.